# Project with external module issue in android studio 3.6

Tags: android, android-studio-3.6

```
Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: No outputs for the main artifact of variant: debug.
```

I am trying to run this project: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack

Comment: put both app:build.gradle and module:build.gradle here

Comment: I am trying to run above project. Thanks

Comment: The link may be gone tomorrow. Please add relevant code/files to your question.

Comment: I gave a workaround solution until the issue is solved on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60423347/292465

Comment: The code was working fine with android studio 3.5 but once i upgrade android studio to 3.6. Then this problem arrived. Thanks

Comment: I know, the same thing happened to me. As I said in previous comment, when you try to run, apk gets built, but it won't install on the device/emulator. You must manually install it. On the other hand, running my other project worked smoothly. If you find something, please, post solution here.

Comment: No, I don't have solution yet.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try "invalite caches/restart"?