# ApkProvisionException after upgrading to android studio 3.6

Tags: android, android-studio

Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: No outputs for the main artifact of variant: debug

There is an application id in my build.gradle file too, but still I am getting this error. Is there any way to get rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with the latest version of Android Studio (3.6). I checked and apk is indeed created in `app/build/outputs/apk/` folder of my project and I guess for now you can just drag'n'drop apk from folder to emulator.